# How do I determine if a method is a generic instance of a generic method

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, generics, equals

I have a MethodInfo passed in to a function and I want to do the following

```
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).GetMethod("Contains");
if (methodInfo.Equals(containsMethod)
{
   // do something
}
```

But this doesn't work because the methodInfo has a specific generic type.  For the example does work if I knew that the ICollection was always of type string.

```
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<string>).GetMethod("Contains");
if (methodInfo.Equals(containsMethod)
{
   // do something
}
```

How can I check whether the MethodInfo is a ANY typed instance of the generic method without caring what the type is?

Thanks.

EDIT: Question clarification

As correctly pointed out the method is not generic but the containing class is so the question is more how to I find out if the MethodInfo is for a Type which is a typed instance of ICollection<>.

EDIT: more context

I am writing a Linq provider and trying to handle the "in" case

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>{ "1", "2" };

from Something s in ...
where myList.Contains(s.name)
select s;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the declaring type:

```
if( methodInfo.Name == "Contains" 
    &&  methodInfo.DeclaringType.IsGenericType
    && methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
{
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `ICollection<T>.Contains` is **not** a generic method - it is a *non-generic* method of a generic type. Otherwise `IsGenericMethod` and `GetGenericTypeDefinition` would help. You could obtain the generic type definition (`DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`) and work back up to `Contains`, but I wonder if you are approaching this problem the hard way.

Usually, if you are using reflection, it may be pragmatic to drop to non-generic `IList` - unless you **need** the type data (for example, for meta-programming). And in that case, I would consider looking closely to see if you can simplify the setup here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Added some context above for what I am trying to achieve.  The DeclaringType approach looks promising, I will try it and get back.

Answer (score 2):

Some error checking would need to  be added to this, but I believe this roughly does what you want. You can use a method with or without a type argument as the parameter.

```
static bool IsContainsMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    Type[] types = { methodInfo.GetParameters().First().ParameterType };
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(types).GetMethod("Contains");
    return methodInfo.Equals(containsMethod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have a generic method: you have a non-generic method on a generic type.  I don't know of a way to use reflection to go directly from a method definition on an open generic type to that same method on a closed generic type or vice versa.  However, you can take advantage of the fact that the methods returned by `GetMethods()` on the open and closed generic types should always be in the same order and do the translation by index:

```
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).GetMethod("Contains");
var methodIndex = Array.IndexOf(methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetMethods(), methodInfo);
var methodOnTypeDefinition = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethods()[methodIndex];
if (methodOnTypeDefinition.Equals(containsMethod))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
    public static bool CheckGenericMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        bool areSimilarMethods = false;
        MethodInfo methodToCompare = typeof(ISomeInterface<>).GetMethod("func");
        Type interfaceInfo = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetInterface(methodToCompare.DeclaringType.FullName);

        if (interfaceInfo != null)
            areSimilarMethods = (methodToCompare.Name.Equals(methodInfo.Name)
            && interfaceInfo.FullName.Contains(methodToCompare.DeclaringType.FullName));
        else
        {
            areSimilarMethods = methodToCompare.DeclaringType.Equals(methodInfo.DeclaringType);
        }

        return areSimilarMethods;

    }
```

and here is the full example usage.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestReflection
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodInfo info1 = typeof(ISomeInterface<>).GetMethod("func");
            MethodInfo info2 = typeof(MyStringCollection).GetMethod("func");
            MethodInfo info3 = typeof(MyProgramCollection).GetMethod("func");
            MethodInfo info4 = typeof(MyXCollection).GetMethod("func");

            if (CheckGenericMethod(info1)) Console.WriteLine("true");else Console.WriteLine("false");
            if (CheckGenericMethod(info2)) Console.WriteLine("true");else Console.WriteLine("false");
            if (CheckGenericMethod(info3)) Console.WriteLine("true");else Console.WriteLine("false");
            if (CheckGenericMethod(info4)) Console.WriteLine("true"); else Console.WriteLine("false");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static bool CheckGenericMethod(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            bool areSimilarMethods = false;
            MethodInfo methodToCompare = typeof(ISomeInterface<>).GetMethod("func");
            Type interfaceInfo = methodInfo.DeclaringType.GetInterface(methodToCompare.DeclaringType.FullName);

            if (interfaceInfo != null)
                areSimilarMethods = (methodToCompare.Name.Equals(methodInfo.Name)
                && interfaceInfo.FullName.Contains(methodToCompare.DeclaringType.FullName));
            else
            {
                areSimilarMethods = methodToCompare.DeclaringType.Equals(methodInfo.DeclaringType);
            }

            return areSimilarMethods;

        }
    }

    public interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : class
    {
        T func(T s);
    }

    public class MyStringCollection : ISomeInterface<string>
    {
        public string func(string s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

    public class MyProgramCollection : ISomeInterface<Program>
    {
        public Program func(Program s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

    public class MyXCollection
    {
        public int func(int s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }

}
```